# How to make hyper number and symbol in the author name of article?

Tags: hyperref

Author names in my article must have numbers 1,2,... and corresponding author must has *. All numbers and symbols must be hyper.How should i make them hyper?
My codes are :

```
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue ,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}  

\begin{document} 

\title{title of article}

\author{first author\href{$^{1,2}$}{$^{1}$},second author \href{$^{1,2}$}{$^{2}$}\thanks{Email address for correspondence:\href{email:}{email address}}\\$^{1,2}$Depart
ment of Electrical Engineering}
```

Numbers 1 and 2 are blue but they don't jump on "Department of Electrical Engineering" part.
Also * after 2 is not blue and hyper to jump on email address.
It seems silly but i couldn't fix this.

Comment: Can you post a working document please, not just fragments?

Comment: First, you can use \textsuperscript\href{URL}{1}.  Second, {^${1,2}$} is not a URL.

Comment: Just tested \href{mailto:email address}{test} and it worked, to my surprise.